# Showing a set is closed in the product topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity, product-space

We have some topological space $X$ with continuous functions $f,g:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ equipped with the usual topology I want to show that then set:
$$E = \{(x,y):f(x)=g(y)\} \subset X \times X $$ is closed in $X \times X$ with the product topology.

So I need to show that $(X \times X) \setminus E$ is open, but I’m not sure how.

Comment: Do you know when a set is open in product topology?

Comment: I disagree (obviously) with the votes to close.  I can agree that the independent effort to solve the problem was on the minimal side, but it wasn't completely absent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $h(x, y)=f(x)-g(y)$ is continuous because $f$ and $g$ are.  Then $(X \times X) \setminus E = h^{-1}(\Bbb R \setminus \{0 \})$.  Since $\Bbb R \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is open and $h$ is continuous, you have the result you need.

Comment: Or more simply: $E = h^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is the inverse image of a closed set hence closed too.